# How to know if a entry of ActiveX in windows registry is not used and can be deleted?

Tags: registry, activex

I am implementing a registry cleaner for `Windows 8` and I know in my registry there is some invalids entries regarding `ActiveX`. But I am not sure about how can I guarantee that the entry is really not necessary anymore.

Does anyone know anything about that?

Answer (score 0):

Only the program that ships the ActiveX knows. For example the component depending on the ActiveX may be set to "install on first use" state, and you can't find out the dependency short of actually installing the component and reverse engineer the component after you get the files.